# Spring Security OAuth 2 in memory token store limit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented REST web services in java spring framework. I have used spring security OAuth2 for authenticating clients.

I have configured `AuthorizationServerTokenServices` to `DefaultTokenServices` and the default token store as `InMemoryTokenStore`.

Now I have few doubts such as,
Does in-memory token store capable of handling thousands of access tokens?
Is it preferable for using in-memory token for large number of clients?
Does in-memory store affects the performance of server?

As mentioned [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) -

> The default InMemoryTokenStore is perfectly fine for a single server.

But I will be having more than one such REST web service applications running on same server.

Comment: I'm afraid you will lose all access tokens in `InMemoryTokenStore` when you restart your authorization server. I'm not so familiar with Spring Security OAuth, but I think `InMemoryTokenStore` should be used only during development and should not be used in a commercial environment.

Comment: I am not bothered about server restart.. I don't want to lose access tokens when server is alive.

Comment: If you use `JdbcTokenStore`, token data will be stored in a relational database. If you use `JwtTokenStore`, values that should be associated with an access token will be embedded in the access token itself, so you don't need a relational database. But, in general, JWT-based access tokens cannot be revoked unless a special mechanism to manage revocation exists.

Comment: Mishty: What did you use then? Did you find out limit?

Comment: @James - I haven't got the answer.